# How to create a Regular Expression that includes all strings of 1 2 and 3 with no more than four 2's?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for something like this: 1* 2<sup>4</sup> 3*

But that doesn't take into account different order like the string 231. Any ideas how to specify the order using regular expressions?

Comment: Apparently your example "regular expression" should be something like `1*2{0,4}3*` where the Kleene star stands for zero or more repetitions, and the braces specify the number of allowed repetitions. Your notation seems to imply that you are looking for a "pure" regular expression, is that correct?

Comment: @triplee yes. I'm looking for the answer conceptually not in code.

Comment: The way that Reguluar expressions were presented to me 1*2{0,4}3* would mean that all the one's would have to appear first. Something like 1*2*|(or)2*1* would represent any string of 1s and/or 2s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your intention was with `1^* 2^4 3^*`, but going from your description,

```
/^([13]*2){0,4}[13]*$/
```

will match any combination of `1`, `2` and `3`, but with no more than four of `2`.

However, you did not specify the regexp engine, so it might not work in some (notably, those without the `{}` repetition operator), in which case you will need to unpack it.

**EDIT**: Having seen tripleee's comment, I finally understood the original attempt. Anyway, in formal regular expression, you definitely need to unpack (not only you don't have `{}`, you don't even have `x?` as shorthand for `(x|ε)`):

```
(1|3)*
(2 (1|3)*
  (2 (1|3)*
    (2 (1|3)*
      (2 (1|3)*
      |ε)
    |ε)
  |ε)
|ε)
```

Comment: +1 Unpacking would yield `^([13]*2([13]*2([13]*2([13]*2)?)?)?)?[13]*$` where `[13]` is a character class matching either 1 or 3, and `?` specifies optionality (zero or one occurrence).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly you want to allow all combinations of `1,2,3` with restriction that digit 2 shouldn't be there more than 4 times.

You need to use lookahead for this regex:

```
^(?!(.*?2){5,})[123]+$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dP2bK3

Comment: "Need to"? No, you don't need to. The restriction is simple enough that this is still a regular language.

Comment: `Need to use` != `must use` :P

Comment: Yes, they are different: "need to" is contingent on a purpose (and is several characters longer). But if we assume one sets out to solve this problem, they are *semantically equivalent in this context*. Either that, or we don't speak the same English.